# PHP, Custom include function - how do I make all other functions & variables accessible?

Tags: php, function, include

I have designed a custom include function for my application, which was meant to make my life much easier except it's done the complete opposite and has resulted in me debugging the same type of errors for hours until this lightbulb moment realising what it was.

Because the files are being included into a function, the variables, functions, etc. inside the file are not global.

Is there any way that I can make it work, or is this whole exercise pointless?

See below for the code.

```
function import($a,$b = 1) { 
    global $options;

        if($b == 1) $folder = "internal_functions";
        elseif($b == 2) $folder = "external_functions";
        else $folder = $b;

        $file_path = $options['LIB_DIR']."/".$folder."/".$a.".php";

        if(@!file_exists($file_path)) {

            $_criticalFiles = array("sessionService/session_loader", "databaseService/db_connection","userService/isLoggedIn");

            if(in_array($a,$_criticalFiles)) {
                die("<center><h1>Critical Error.<br />Could not find {$a}.</h1></center>");
            }

        } else {
            require_once($file_path);
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: can you also add what's inside `$a.php` ?

Comment: `$a.php` is the variable name for the file and `$b` is the variable name for the folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those of you wondering how I got around this, I didn't.

Instead I put all the files in an array such as

```
$filesInclude = array("file1","file2","file3","etc");
```

2 different arrays for both local and external files, then just ran a for loop on the array. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem of [scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Any variables created in the function which you want available outside it will have to be `global`ized.

Comment: I understand this, but is there a way of doing it as a 2 birds 1 stone method or will I have to initialise each individual variable?

Comment: Frayed knot -- you'll have to do each one, and that doesn't take care of any functions defined in the external file. Hmm.... [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) *may* do something for you, I'm not sure, I'd have to fiddle around with it, and it's late and I'm tired. Check it out.

Comment: Appreciate the help - just cut all that out and threw what was in the import($a,$b) function into a for loop and put the includes in an array. :)